# How to add additional fields to 'Items to invoice' Grid? in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to add extra attribute under SKU in first tab `Sales->Orders->OrderId'#100000001'->Invoice`

[image]

I'm new to this task..Can anyone help me For this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by override theme template..You need to create custom admin theme

```
app/etc/local.xml
```

Add following code to create custom theme

```
<config> 
......
    <stores>
        <admin>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <design>
                <theme>
                    <default>custom</default>
                </theme>
            </design>
        </admin>
    </stores>
......
</config>
```

Go to:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

Copy the file to:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/custom/template/sales/order/invoice/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

put this code:

```
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
```

behind:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_item->setStoreId($_item->getInvoice()->getStoreId()) ?>
<?php $this->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
```

and then:

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attributecode')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

behind:

```
<td><?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?>
```

Comment: Yes i found already...Is this right way to edit admin theme.....Better i need to create custom admin theme and edit can done in my theme...Can you please explain how to create admin theme?